# How to put certain columns to another datagridview?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am very new with programming. Let's say, I have a excel with Column A, Column B, Column C, and Column D. 
What I want is to read this excel file, puts all data into a datagridview, and select some certain columns from it and transfer to another new datagridview.

The problems I have is I dont know how to put certain columns from the datagridview and transfer them to another new datagridview.

Can anyone help me!!
Please!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Testing9
{
public partial class ExcelModifer : Form
{
    public ExcelModifer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnChooseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox_path.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            LoadExcel();
        }
    }

    private void LoadExcel()
    {
        OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textBox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\";");
        oconn.Open();
        DataTable dbSchema = oconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet.");
        }
        string firstSheetName = dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + firstSheetName + "]", oconn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save as Excel File";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files(2003)|*.xls|Excel Files(2007)|*.xlsx";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            //Change properties of the Workbook
            ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;
            //Storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            ExcelApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How can I copy Datagridview column from one to another ? Please, is anyone know ?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in DataGridViewRows and assign values step by step to whereever you want.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
           // make some assignment in this block.
        }
     }
```

Comment: but how can I copy certain Column ?

Comment: row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString(); it would be help.

Comment: what if I dont know the column name, the excel file do not have a column header, How do use it? something likes Column[0]??

Comment: yes, you can use indexNumber instead of column name. check out the link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you should create an another datatable and add certain column to this datatable and then bind 2nd datatble to other gridview.